# loadMoreRows not called on load

Tags: react-virtualized

I have the following example implementing the `InfiniteLoader` with a `Table`. The problem is that `loadMoreRows` is not called on load or when the component is mounted. However, if I manually execute the API call and pass the result through `props`, `loadMoreRows` is called with startIndex 0 and thus I have the same API call twice.

```
import React = require('react');
import _ = require('lodash');
import Immutable = require('immutable');
import Api = require('./Api');

const STATUS_LOADING = 1,
      STATUS_LOADED = 2,
      LOG_LIMIT = 200;

interface Props {
    logEntries: Immutable.List<Immutable.Map<string, any>>;
}

interface State {
    logEntries?: Immutable.List<Immutable.Map<string, any>>;
    count?: number;
    loadedRowsMap?: any;
}

class LogViewer extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            logEntries: props.logEntries,
            count: 0,
            loadedRowsMap: {}
        };
    }

    render() {
        return {this.renderLoader()};
    }

    private renderLoader() {
        const {logEntries, count} = this.state;
        return (
            <InfiniteLoader isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded.bind(this)}
                            loadMoreRows={this.loadMoreRows.bind(this)}
                            minimumBatchSize={LOG_LIMIT}
                            rowCount={logEntries.size} >
                {
                    ({onRowsRendered, registerChild}) => (
                        <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                            {
                                ({width}) => (
                                    <Table headerHeight={20}
                                           height={400}
                                           onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                                           ref={registerChild}
                                           rowCount={count}
                                           className='log-entries'
                                           gridClassName='grid'
                                           headerStyle={{ fontSize: 15 }}
                                           rowGetter={({index}) => logEntries.get(index)}
                                           rowHeight={50}
                                           width={width} >
                                        <Column label='Name'
                                                key='name'
                                                dataKey='name'
                                                width={200} />
                                    </Table>
                                )
                            }
                        </AutoSizer>
                    )
                }
            </InfiniteLoader>
        );
    }

    private isRowLoaded({index}) {
        const {loadedRowsMap} = this.state;
        return !!loadedRowsMap[index];
    }

    private loadMoreRows({startIndex, stopIndex}) {
        const {loadedRowsMap, level, logEntries} = this.state;

        _.range(startIndex, stopIndex).forEach(i => {
            loadedRowsMap[i] = STATUS_LOADING;
        });
        this.setState({ loadedRowsMap });

        const offset = Math.floor((startIndex + 1) / LOG_LIMIT);
        return Api.logs(LOG_LIMIT, offset)
            .then(({body: [count, logs]}) => {
                _.range(startIndex, stopIndex).forEach(i => {
                    loadedRowsMap[i] = STATUS_LOADED;
                });
                const newLogs = logEntries.toJS().concat(logs);
                this.setState({
                    count,
                    logEntries: Immutable.fromJS(newLogs),
                    loadedRowsMap
                });
            });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that `loadMoreRows` is not called on load or when the component is mounted.

[Any time a range of rows loads](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/29752372a7ceae441564fe29795c427d1ccb0bc3/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.js#L117-L123), `InfiniteLoader` [calls `isRowLoaded` for each row](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/29752372a7ceae441564fe29795c427d1ccb0bc3/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.js#L172) to determine if it needs to be loaded. If `isRowLoaded` returns false, then that row is queued up and [`loadMoreRows` is called in chunks for each range of unloaded rows](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/29752372a7ceae441564fe29795c427d1ccb0bc3/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.js#L85-L89).

In your case above, I *believe* what's happening is that you're not passing any initial rows to the `Table`- so `Grid` is not rendering anything initially (because it has no rows to render) and so the rows-loaded caller I linked above has nothing to iterate over and nothing to load. You have a couple of options here- either kick off the first load yourself, or add a +1 empty row to tip `InfiniteLoader` off that it should request more data ([like I do in this example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/creatingAnInfiniteLoadingList.md)).

Comment: I think the problem was that I didn't set the status to loaded for the initial logs. Thanks, this part works now!